# Considerations about ec primes Is the order of $79\cdot 3^k\pmod {71}$ involved?

Tags: number-theory

Ec primes are primes of the form:

$(2^n-1)\cdot 10^d+2^{n-1}-1$, where d Is the Number of decimal digits of $2^{n-1}$.

n's leading to an ec probable prime are:

$79,2131,19179=2131\cdot 9,69660$

I noticed that

$2131\equiv -2\pmod {79}$

$2131\equiv 1\pmod {71}$

Using CRT this leads to a precise form of $2131$, which Is a Number of the form $-3478+5609\cdot s$

$69660$ Is $9\cdot 7740$, but $7740$ Is again a Number of the above form $-3478+5609\cdot s$

$69660\equiv 2131\cdot 9\pmod {71\cdot 79\cdot 9}$

$79\cdot 9=711$

$79\cdot 3^3=2133$

I wonder if the order of $79*3^q\pmod {71}$ has something to do with these exponents leading to a prime.

And maybe all this Is linked to the fact that

$6^6\equiv 9\equiv 19179\equiv 69660\pmod {71}$?

I wonder if a hint could be:

$79\cdot 3\cdot 6^3\equiv 1\equiv 72^2\pmod {71}$

$92020$ Is another exponent n leading to a prp.

$(72^2-79\cdot 9-1)$ divides the difference of $92020$ and $69660$.